# Selecting JSON object data table element to list all its elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm working on something that's a little over my head and I can't seem to find any libraries that relate to this. In the web application that I'm working on, I have a list of n people and upon clicking on a person's name, a list of n articles written by that person will be generated. I am trying to accomplish this using JavaScript and JSON.

This is how my JSON data will be structured:

```
var people = {
    'clients': [
        {
            'fname': 'joe',
            'lname': 'smith',
            'AFD': [
                {
                    'articleName': 'AFDArticle1byjoe'
                },
                {
                    'articleName': 'AFDArticle2byjoe'
                },
                {
                    'articleName': 'AFDArticle3byjoe'
                },
                {
                    'articleName': 'AFDArticle4byjoe'
                },
                {
                    'articleName': 'AFDArticle5byjoe'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            'fname': 'jim',
            'lname': 'Hoff',
            'AFD': [
                {
                    'articleName': 'AFDArticle12byjim'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            'fname': 'rick',
            'lname': 'Robinson',
            'AFD': [
                {
                    'articleName': 'AFDArticle5byrick'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            'fname': 'sarah',
            'lname': 'Ross',
            'AFD': [
                {
                    'articleName': 'AFDArticle20bysarah'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            'fname': 'jack',
            'lname': 'jones',
            'AFD': [
                {
                    'articleName': 'AFDArticle9byjack'
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
};
```

Everyone has a first name, last name, and a list of n AFD Articles.

This code will nicely list out the number of n people in an HTML table from the JSON example above:

```
<table border="1">
<script>
for (var i=0;i<people.clients.length;i++)
{

    $("#tabX").append("<tr><td>"+people.clients[i].fname+"</td></tr>");

}
</script>
</table>
```

and so I'll get some nice output of the first names in a table like so:
"joe jim rick sarah jack"

And so by clicking on "joe", a data table of Joe's articles will be generated. I can already accomplish this like so:

```
<table border="1">
<script>
    for (var i=0;i<people.clients.length;i++)
    {
        $("#tabX").append("<tr><td>"+people.clients[ selectedClient ].AFD[i].articleName+"</td></tr>");
    }
</script>
</table>
```

Where "selectedClient" is the client that's currently selected, AFD articles will be generated like so: AFD Article 1 by joe, ... , AFD Article 4 by joe.

So finally! I have some questions that would really help me get through this. How could I change the value of selectedClient after clicking on someone's name? Could this be possibly done by executing a function like below?

```
$("#tabX").append("<tr><td><a href="javascript:selectName();">" +people.clients[i].fname+ "</a></td></tr>");
```

Comment: can you make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bJ3eM/

Comment: I have updated your fiddle. Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/bJ3eM/2/

Comment: unbelievable, thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are on the right track. May be something like this will help:

```
$("#tabX").append("<tr><td><a href=\"javascript:;\" onclick=\"javascript:selectName("+i+");\">" +people.clients[i].fname+ "</a></td></tr>");
```

and then this will be your selectName function:

```
function selectName (idx)
{
  selectedClient = idx;
}
```

Comment: You could probably make this code more succinct by creating DOM nodes in Javascript, and adding the event handlers there before outputting it to the page.

Comment: What does the code `var node = document.getElementById('tabA');

  while (node.hasChildNodes()) {
    node.removeChild(node.lastChild);
  }` Do exactly in the jfiddle that you've provided? I'm trying to understand it since I need to now add the ability to populate a DOM after selecting one of the KCS articles from any of the people.

Comment: the while loop is to remove all the rows of the table with id tabA. So when you select a particular name, the code will remove any existing rows for that table and then will add new rows for the selected name. Also look at @Andy 's solution below, its more elegant.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would approach it.

I assume the following HTML:

```
<table id="people"></table>
<div id="articles"></div>
```

And the following Javascript. [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is IE9 and above.

So for each person on your client list, add them to the table, ensuring that you set the `data` id to that client's index in the JS object, and include a class name.

```
people.clients.forEach(function(el, i) {
   $('#people').append('<tr><td data-id="' + i + '" class="name">' + el.fname + '</td></td>');
});
```

Then, when you click on an element with a `name` class name, pick up the id from the data attribute, loop through the AFDs for that client using the id and append them to the div (or element of your choice.). This makes the further assumption that between the time you list your clients and you start clicking on their names you're not sorting the people object, otherwise the indexes (ids) will be all out of wack.

```
$('.name').click(function() {
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  people.clients[id].AFD.forEach(function(el, i){
    $('#articles').append('<div>' + el.articleName + '</div>');
  });
});
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z86XC/3/)